# Using rails form to populate model with hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hash, model

I am currently working on a simple rails4 app. As part of the app, I am creating a form to populate the database and a particular column (:additional), I would like to populate with a hash where the key is a string (heading) and the value an array of strings (paragraphs below heading). So, for example: `{"Heading" => ["Paragraph1", "Paragraph2"]}` etc.

I am confused how I would now set up a form using rails to populate this column. I was thinking of creating a text_field for the title and then one or more text_areas underneath for the paragraphs and then somehow merging them in the controller but when creating the fields, I have to give the object as :additional which leads to problems.

How would I go about best accomplishing this? Is it even possible or should I restructure my database somehow?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: see this http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1):

If you're using postgres, ActiveRecord has support for using :hstore as the column type. If you're not, you can use [serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize).

Comment: Looking into :hstore right now. I am using serialize right now but that doesn't solve the problem of how to get the data from the form into the controller.

Comment: I think `store` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html would be better than `serialize`.